# How is Kubernetes Service IP assigned and stored?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, k8s-serviceaccount

I deployed a service `myservice` to the k8s cluster. Using `kubectl describe serivce ...`, I can find that the service ip is `172.20.127.114`  I am trying to figure out how this service ip is assigned. Is it assigned by K8s controller and stored in DNS?  How does K8S control decide on the IP range?

```
kubectl describe service myservice                                     

Name:              myservice
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=myservice
                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=myservice
Annotations:       argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: 3
Selector:          app=myservice
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                172.20.127.114
IPs:               172.20.127.114
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        5000/TCP
Endpoints:         10.34.188.30:5000,10.34.89.157:5000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: thank you! How can i check the entries in coredns?

Comment: coredns is responsible to translate `myservice` to `172.20.127.114`   . kube-proxy stores `172.20.127.114` to endpoints mapping

Answer (score 1):

kuebernetes controller accepts service CIDR range using service-cluster-ip-range parameter. Service IP is assigned from this CIDR block.

[image]

The kubernetes controller pod name might vary in each environment. update the pod name accordingly

Comment: thank you! i am using EKS .The command does not return CIDR block info. 

     kubectl get po -n kube-system kube-controller-manager-controlplane -o yaml | grep service-cluster-ip-range
      Error from server (NotFound): pods "kube-controller-manager-controlplane" not found

Comment: the kubernetes controller pod name might vary in each environment. update the pod name accordingly

Answer (score 1):

- The Pod IP Addresses comes from **`CNI`**
- `Api-server`, `Etcd`, `Kube-Proxy`, `Scheduler` and `controller-Manager` IP
  Addresses come from **`Server/Node`** IP Address
- `Service` IP address range is defined in the **`API Server`** Configuration

---

If we check API Configuration, we can see the `- --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12` option in command section, A CIDR notation IP range from which to assign service cluster IPs:

```bash
sudo vim /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
```

See all defaults configurations:

```bash
kubeadm config print init-defaults
```

```bash
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
bootstrapTokens:
  - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers:kubeadm:default-node-token
    token: abcdef.0123456789abcdef
    ttl: 24h0m0s
    usages:
      - signing
      - authentication
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 1.2.3.4
  bindPort: 6443
nodeRegistration:
  criSocket: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  name: node
  taints: null
---
apiServer:
  timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
clusterName: kubernetes
controllerManager: { }
dns: { }
etcd:
  local:
    dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
imageRepository: k8s.gcr.io
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: 1.24.0
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
scheduler: { }
```

---

##### Change Default CIDR IP Range

You can configure Kube API Server with many different options:

1. when bootstrapping the cluster via `kubeadm init --service-cidr <IP Range>`
2. Change `kube-apiserver` directly (`kubelet` periodically scans the configurations for changes)

```bash
sudo vim /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
```

- Note that with option number `2`, you are going to get The `connection to  the server IP:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`
  error for a while, so you have to wait a couple of minutes to `kube-apiserver` start again...
- The new CIDR block only applies for **newly** created Services, which means
  old Services still remain in the old CIDR block, for testing:

```bash
kubectl create service clusterip test-cidr-block --tcp 80:80
```

Then Check the newly created Service...

---

- [Credit](https://github.com/alifiroozi80/CKA/tree/main/CKA#configure-service-ip-address)